# Proving that $\|f-f_n\|_{2}\to 0\Leftrightarrow \|f_n\|_{2}\to \|f\|_{2}$ when $\int f_ng\to \int fg$ for all $g\in L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)\in L^2(X)$ and $f\in L^2(X)$ such that $\int_{X} f_ng\to \int_{X}fg$ for all $g\in L^2(X)$.

Show that $\left\|f-f_n\right\|_{2}\to 0 \Leftrightarrow \left\|f_n\right\|_{2}\to \left\|f\right\|_{2}$.

I have this:

$(\Leftarrow) $\begin{eqnarray} \left\|f-f_n\right\|_{2}^2&=&\langle f-f_n,f-f_n\rangle\\
&=&\|f\|_{2}^{2}-2\langle f_n,f\rangle+\|f_n\|_{2}^{2}\\
&=&\|f\|_{2}^{2}-2\int ff_n+\|f_n\|_{2}^{2}\\
&\to& \|f\|_{2}^2-2\int f^2+\|f\|_{2}^2 \quad(\text{ because } \int f_nf\to \int f^2)\\
&=&2(\int |f|^2-\int f^2)
\end{eqnarray}

But, $f^2\neq |f|^2$ in general... How can I conclude that $\|f_n-f\|_{2}\to 0$?

$(\Rightarrow)$ By Triangle inequality, $|f|\leq |f_n|+|f-f_n|\Rightarrow |f|^2\leq |f_n|^2+|f-f_n|^2+2|f_n||f-f_n|$ then
\begin{eqnarray} 
\int (|f|^2-|f_n|^2)&\leq& \int |f-f_n|^2+2\int |f_n||f-f_n|\\
&\leq& \int |f-f_n|^2+2\|f_n\|_{2}\|f-f_n\|_{2} \text{ (Holder Inequality)}
\end{eqnarray}
but I get circular reasoning, because I would like $\|f_n\|_{2}\to \|f\|_{2}$ (to conclude that the right side of the last inequality tends to zero)
but that is what I would like to proves ... how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: $
\left| {\left\| f \right\|_2  - \left\| {f_n } \right\|_2 } \right| \le \left\| {f - f_n } \right\|_2 
$ holds in general by the reverse triangle inequality. So the direction $
 \Rightarrow$ is trivial.

Comment: Oh, true! then I must fix the first implication

Comment: By the assumption, with $g:=f$, $
\left\langle {f_n ,f} \right\rangle  \to \left\langle {f,f} \right\rangle  = \left\| f \right\|_2^2 $. And you are done ($
\left\| {f - f_n } \right\|^2  \to \left\| f \right\|_2^2  - 2\left\| f \right\|_2^2  + \left\| f \right\|_2^2  = 0$).

Comment: Your mistake is forgetting that the $L^2$ inner product has a complex conjugate on the second argument

Comment: all reason. I had forgotten that detail. Thanks a lot